# Laravel Carbon format date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I am posting via ajax a date from my form which is in the format.

27/07/2016

When it hits my controller I convert the format to Y-m-d as It is store in my database like that.

However I'm getting the following error:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (27/07/2016) at
>   position 0 (2): Unexpected character

**My controller**

```
public function call(Request $request)
    {              
        return Company->expenses()->where('date_expense', Carbon::parse($request->start)->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
    }
```

On my expenses model I have the following defined as dates:

```
protected $dates = ['date_expense'];
```

Comment: you're passing a date when it's looking for a timestamp, convert to timestamp first then pass it in.

Comment: How do I change? Sorry @VikingBlooded

Comment: format("Y-m-d H:i:s)

Comment: Try doing `Carbon::createFromFormat` instead of `Carbon::parse`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Carbon's `Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);` method:

```
$start = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->start);

return Company->expenses()->where('date_expense', $start)->get();
```

By the way, there is no need to further format the date as Laravel knows how to handle Carbon objects and will do that automatically for you behind the scenes.

Comment: It won't be `dd/mm/yyyy` - it'll be whatever the format is in PHP's `date()` command - but otherwise +1.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->start)->format('d/m/Y')
```

You have to change your code with this

```
return Company->expenses()->where('date_expense', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->start)->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your laravel framework version is 5.0+
you can check by `php artisan -V`

mine is `Laravel Framework 5.4.19`
you can make a reference from laravel document https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

The following is an example:

1. if your laravel Framework doesn't contains Carbon ,you can run

   `composer require nesbot/carbon`
2. at your model such as Post model

```
class Post extends Model`
{
    protected $fillable = ["title","body"];`

    protected $dates = [`
        'created_at',`
        'updated_at',`
        'deleted_at'`
    ];
}
```

3. use tinker to add a post
   open terminal under project directory
   run
   `php artisan tinker`

`App\Post::create("title"=>"This is Title","body"=>"this is body")`

and then you can get lastest created post's created_at by Carbon

by `App\Post::latest()->get()->created_at->diffForHumans()`

you can also use same method in blade like this
`{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}`

the Carbon document url is as followed: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/